# Sandbox cannot add funds

Tags: paypal-sandbox

I'm having grief with the new PayPal Developer site and Sandbox.  I've created a personal account in the Developer but the funds I added are not showing up.  I read a forum post that you had to add funds via the Sandbox login but it won't let me add funds either.

Phil

Answer (score 7):

You have to login at https://developer.paypal.com with your developer account and then go to Applications->Sandbox Accounts->Create Account, the 5th field is "PayPal balance" here you can put any amount you want to your test account.

Comment: Ron, I assume you mean login with my normal PayPal account details?  I login with my normal paypal account details go to Applications->Sandbox Accounts->Create Account, enter an amount, then when I save it and go back and look in Profile > Funding no money is shown.

Comment: Phil, you can create Sandbox Test Accounts from either the Sandbox (https://www.sandbox.paypal.com) or the Developer Site (https://developer.paypal.com).

i've try adding a Personal account from the Developer site like this Applications->Sandbox Accounts->Create Account, created an test account just fine with $75 balance.

and then login in the sandbox with the credentials created in Developer, and displays the $75 balance correctly.

Comment: i did enter with my normal paypal account details

Comment: Can I add money to existing account?

Comment: This does not answer the question of how to put money on an account. 
In my instance, I need to put money on the BUSINESS account and don't want to integrate with that portion of the API just to transfer money from another sandbox account.  tanks @Muk for the easy and IMO right way to do this (unless you actually need a new sandbox user too)

Answer (score 3):

Go to https://www.sandbox.paypal.com

There use the option Send Money

Comment: you can send a "generous" amount from 1 test account to another, an amount that can virtually run forever in tests :)

Comment: yeah but lol as the sandbox site is a replica of the real paypal I have to wait 5 days for the test money to clear after the transfer is accepted by the facilitator account so now I have to go and work on something else mean time even though I'm ready now (this is funny and retarded paypal)

Answer (score 0):

"PayPal balance" here you can put less then 5000 amount.